# returning a value with jOOQ and PostgreSQL serial and RETURNING

Tags: java, postgresql, sql-insert, jooq, sql-returning

I have a PostgreSQL `uris` table with serial (autoincrementing) `uri_id` column and string `uri` column. I can query the table fine using jOOQ:

```
createDSLContext().select(fieldByName("uri_id")).from(tableByName("uris"))
    .where(fieldByName("uri").equal(uri.toString())).fetchOne(0, Integer.class))
```

That returns a Java `Integer`. But when I insert a new URI, I want to get back the generated `uri_id` key, so I try this:

```
createDSLContext().insertInto(tableByName("uris"), fieldByName("uri"))
    .values(uri.toString()).returning(fieldByName("uri_id")).fetchOne().getValue(0, Integer.class)
```

This time I get an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field 0 is not contained in list
```

Just as a test, I tried supplying a literal value for `uri_id` in the `INSERT` statement, but still got the error.

It looks like the correct SQL is being generated:

```
insert into "uris" ("uri") values ('http://example.com/') returning "uri_id"
```

But the returned record is empty. This is true even when I specify a literal `uri_id` in the insert statement.

How can I retrieve an auto-generated column from a PostgreSQL `INSERT` statement using jOOQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is also being discussed more in detail on the [jOOQ user group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jooq-user/pgfzUfbystk).

Essentially, you're running into a known issue where the `RETURNING` clause is currently not supported by jOOQ 3.3 (and lower) when used with plain SQL, instead of with generated tables. This is the issue reference:

https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2374